# Node.js relative require paths to executing script

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I make require look in the relative path of the executing script (not whatever script has require'd the executing script)? Example:

index.js

```
require('lib/foo.js');
```

--

lib/foo.js

```
var barFunction = require('./bar.js').barFunction;
barFunction();
```

--

lib/bar.js

```
module.exports.barFunction = function(){
    return true;
}
```

When you `node index.js`, foo.js looks for bar.js instead of lib/bar.js.

If foo.js is amended to `require('lib/bar.js')`, then `node foo.js` will stop working.

How can I set up require in a way that I can both `node index.js` and `node lib/foo.js` and have then both work?

Comment: Did you try using `./lib/foo.js` instead of `lib/foo.js`? Other than that, there isn't anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @mscdex: That won't work if I `node foo.js` directly in the lib folder. I need that to work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) to get the absolute directory the currently executing script resides in. For example:

`index.js`:

```
require(__dirname + '/lib/foo.js');
```

---

`lib/foo.js`:

```
var barFunction = require(__dirname + '/bar.js').barFunction;
barFunction();
```